# Need to allow a user to restart bind9

Tags: bind, start

I want to give the www-data user the ability to restart bind9 using this command

service bind9 restart

At the moment, they can execute it and it will stop bind9 but not restart it again complaining that permissions will not allow a chmod of the file "named".

can you point me in the direction of what i need to do

**Update**

Okay so I added the line to the sudoers as requested.

```
www-data      ALL=NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/bind9
```

It still has some issue:

```
root@LAMPREY:~# su www-data
$ service bind9 restart
 * Stopping domain name service... bind9                                        rndc: error: none:0: open: /etc/bind/rndc.key: permission denied
rndc: could not load rndc configuration
                                                                         [ OK ]
 * Starting domain name service... bind9                                        chmod: changing permissions of `/var/run/named': Operation not permitted
$ exit
```

I also then tried running another command

```
/etc/init.d/bind9 restart
 * Stopping domain name service... bind9                                        rndc: error: none:0: open: /etc/bind/rndc.key: permission denied
rndc: could not load rndc configuration
                                                                         [ OK ]
 * Starting domain name service... bind9                                        chmod: changing permissions of `/var/run/named': Operation not permitted
$ exit
```

with the same result

Comment: you can give them sudo access to only run that command?

Comment: You need to run `sudo service bind9 restart`.

Comment: Why would the webserver need to **restart** bind? A simple **reload** should be sufficient. `bind` will re-verify the root zone after a restart, which can take several seconds, and requests are queued during that time.

Comment: You. Do. Not. Need. Sudo. To. Restart. Bind. Check my answer, set up `/etc/rndc.conf` with proper access restrictions and never *EVER* mention " `www-data` " and " `sudo` access " in the same sentence again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why would you not want to give the user access to to `sudo` to run this specific command ? This is exactly the situation that sudo is designed for.

Adding

```
www-data somehost= /sbin/service bind9 restart
```

will grant the user www-data permission to run `service bind9 restart` (and only that command) on somehost.

Comment: What file do I add this too?

Comment: you use `visudo` to edit the `sudoers` file

Comment: Using `sudo` to administer bind is bloody overkill, and giving `sudo` access to the `www-data` user is a terrible idea. Setting up `rndc` is much safer, simpler *and* opens up a whole slew of additional possibilities.

Comment: @Shadur: the command only allows www-data to restart bind nothing more. It does exactly what the OP requires and asked for.

Comment: `sudo` is not immune to security flaws. Neither are most web-based applications.

Answer (score 7):

To answer all three above: `sudo` is bloody overkill when `rndc` already has the capability you need, plus the option to reload nameservers *other* than the one on localhost.

The script `rndc-confgen` will generate an rndc.conf file for you that you can save to  `/etc/rndc.conf` and make readable to `www-data`:

```
shadur@Romulus:~$ rndc-confgen 
# Start of rndc.conf
key "rndc-key" {
    algorithm hmac-md5;
    secret "zGHUrg0X5Id4rn27A0Nb9A==";
};

options {
    default-key "rndc-key";
    default-server 127.0.0.1;
    default-port 953;
};
# End of rndc.conf

# Use with the following in named.conf, adjusting the allow list as needed:
# key "rndc-key" {
#   algorithm hmac-md5;
#   secret "zGHUrg0X5Id4rn27A0Nb9A==";
# };
# 
# controls {
#   inet 127.0.0.1 port 953
#       allow { 127.0.0.1; } keys { "rndc-key"; };
# };
# End of named.conf
```

The commented-out part can then be added to `/etc/bind/named.conf` in order to tell the server that it should respond properly to that key (which is randomly generated when you run `rndc-confgen`.

After you've done the above and restarted bind once, the www-data user should be able to issue commands to bind via the `rndc` command.

`rndc restart` will restart the server completely;
`rndc reconfig` will cause it to reload its `named.conf` file;
`rndc reload` will check and reload all zones;
`rndc reload <zone>` will check and reload just .

There's other commands as well; you can get a list by simply typing `rndc` without any commands.

Don't use a chainsaw when a scalpel will do; don't use `sudo` when you don't even need to be root.

Answer (score 3):

why not give them sudo rights to just restart bind?

```
www-data      ALL=NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/bind9
```

Then you can run it and it should work.. Also you could use rndc if you setup your keys to reload bind

Comment: What file do I add this too?

Comment: Because `sudo` is bloody overkill, especially if you're going to use it to allow root access -- no matter how carefully limited; `sudo` is not 100% free from exploit risks itself -- to the apache user.

Comment: @Shadur paranoid much?

Comment: Sysadmin. It comes with the territory.

Answer (score 3):

Completing @Mike's answer

Run `visudo` and the file `/etc/sudoers` will open in your default text editor. Do not open the file in any other way.

Then add the following line, preferably at the end

```
www-data      ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service bind9 restart
```

Save and exit the editor. Now the user www-data can run the following in order to restart bind

```
sudo /usr/sbin/service bind9 restart
```

Comment: For the love of $deity, don't use `sudo` to allow people to restart bind, the whole point of the `rndc` subsystem was to not require root permissions...

Comment: This is a solution to the problem as asked. We do not have any details on why the OP needs this (any crazy reason). Providing an alternative like rndc would require some discussion with OP and a more elaborate answer, to which I personally didn't have enough time for. I just clarified a previously given answer. You are right though, I should at least mention `rndc`. I see that you provided your answer, which deserves a +1.

Answer (score 0):

rndc reload should work fine from within a PHP system() call without modification of specific permissions. I agree that restarting bind is unnecessary, since if you allow the user to do that, you'd probably end up spending more time restarting the service than it is actually up and online to serve requests.